# SQL Server : How to copy a particular table from one schema to other schema on the same db,same server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have `Employee` database which has two schemas, `dbo` and `emp_test`.
I want to copy `dbo.employee_salary` and create the same table in the `emp_test` schema.

I tried with SSMS -> DB -> Tasks -> Export option but I couldn't do that. Do we have any SQL script to achieve the same? Kindly advise.

Comment: Selest into, and script table as create. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no TSQL command to script or copy a table.  You can use

```
select *
into dbo.SomeTable
from dbo.SomeOtherTable
```

but that will create an unindexed heap table, without any constraints.

The normal workflow here would be to use SSMS to script the table as create to new Query Editor Window, edit the script to change the names of the table, indexes, constraints, etc, and run it.  Followed by running

```
insert into dbo.SomeTable (col1,col2,...)
select col1, col2, . . .
from dbo.SomeOtherTable
```

If you don't want to type all the column names you can left-click-drag the columns folder under the table in SSMS and drop onto a query window.  This will  paste a comma-delimited list of table columns.